# Secure what exactly from general quarters?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *[Greyhound (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greyhound_(film))*, from Fletcher-class destroyer, Commander Ernest commands Taker
& Helmsman to destroy German U-boat, which was following 37 Allied ships,
which are making its way to Liverpool. They successfully destroyed it:

> Commander Ernest: **Secure from general quarters**. Take us to Condition 3
> and arrange for hot food if at all possible.
>
> Taker: Aye, aye, sir

Secure what exactly from general quarters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secure has the following meaning (from Meriam-Webster)

> 4: to release (naval personnel) from work or duty

And the 'general quaters' means (from Wikipedia):

> an announcement made aboard a naval warship to signal that all hands
> aboard a ship must go to battle stations as quickly as possible.

Combining two meanings, we have 'release (naval personnel) from the work in battle stations' for the meaning of the phrase 'Secure from general quarters'.